# SVG: Connect vertical and horizontal dotted path in a non square container

Tags: svg

I'm trying to create a connected vertical and horizontal line using SVG path.

The container is not square (height: 200px, width: 400px).
This resolves in some weird graphics where the vertical line looks different from the horizontal.
I want the vertical line to look like the horizontal line. How can I do that? 
If the container is square the problem is not present,  but that is not a solution I can use. 
Example code:

```
<svg height="200" width="400" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" fill="none" d="M1 1 v53 h55" stroke-dasharray="5,5" />
</svg>
```

Please see this for example: https://jsfiddle.net/x5bgukar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can force uniform scaling with [`preserveAspectRatio='xMinYMin'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

```html
    <svg height="200" width="400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" fill="none" d="M1 1 v53 h55" stroke-dasharray="5,5" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `viewbox` according to the width and height:

```
<svg height="200" width="400" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
    <path stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" fill="none" d="M1 1 v53 h55" stroke-dasharray="5,5" stroke-dashoffset="0.00" />
</svg>
```